BeanCreationException is happening while starting app for 'FlywayIntializer' bean,
My project has been working fine earlier but now all of sudden I am getting the below error. Nothing has been changed. I have tried changing the version of flyway in pom as well as changing the spring boot version. Its a spring boot project with React. ANy directions are helpful.
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: [jcc][t4][2043][12249][4.31.10] Exception {0}: Error opening socket to server {1} on port {2} with message: {3}. ERRORCODE=-4296, SQLSTATE=08001

